# Cannot unmarshal struct from unmanaged code in Mono

Tags: mono, marshalling

**Problem:**

I can successfully marshal a struct with root elements as well as array elements into unmanaged code, but cannot get the root element data back (the array elements come back correct). I have tried a number of approaches, but none worked so far. Here is the simplest one below.

I have read at [http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries](http://I%20can%20successfully%20marshal%20a%20struct%20with%20root%20elements%20as%20well%20as%20array%20elements%20into%20unmanaged%20code,%20but%20cannot%20get%20the%20root%20element%20data%20back%20%28the%20array%20elements%20come%20back%20correct%29.%20I%20have%20tried%20a%20number%20of%20approaches,%20but%20none%20worked%20so%20far.%20Here%20is%20the%20simplest%20one%20below.%20%20I%20have%20read%20at%20http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries%20and%20think%20I%27m%20doing%20everything%20correctly.) and think I'm doing everything correctly (but obviously not ;-)

**Implementation:**

C# declarations:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
private struct Vector3
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
private struct MeshData
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public Vector3[] vertices;
    public int verticeCount;
}

[DllImport("MeshPlugin")]
private static extern bool ImportMesh([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] MeshData meshData);
```

Native C declarations:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct VECTOR3
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} VECTOR3;

#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct MESHDATA
{
    VECTOR3 *vertices;
    int verticeCount;
} MESHDATA;
```

Called from C# like this:

```
<defined vertices and length...>

MeshData meshData = new MeshData();
meshData.vertices = mesh.vertices; // note that vertices[0].x = 111
meshData.verticeCount = 1;
ImportMesh(meshData); // calls native function
Debug.Log(meshData.vertices[0].x); // prints  222 which is correct, so array got marshaled back okay
Debug.Log(meshData.verticeCount); //  **prints 1 which is incorrect** so the int element did not come back okay
```

Native implementation:

```
bool ImportMesh(MESHDATA *meshData)
{
    printf("%f", meshData->vertices[0].x); // prints 111 which is correct
    meshData->vertices[0].x = 222; // change to see if it gets back okay
    printf("%d", meshData->verticeCount); // prints 1 which is correct
    meshData->verticeCount = 2; // change to see if it gets back okay
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that sub-array values of the struct are returned correctly, but that the main struct elements are not.

I also tried this in C#:

```
[DllImport("MeshPlugin")]
private static extern bool ImportMesh(IntPtr meshData);

int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MeshData));
IntPtr pMeshData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(meshData, pMeshData, false);
ImportMesh(pMeshData);
meshData = (MeshData)(Marshal.PtrToStructure(pMeshData, typeof(MeshData)));
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pMeshData);
```

And this one crashes badly on return (but the log shows that the native code executed and printed the correct values on the native side).

I have tried other permutations with attribute decorators, etc., but the mono compiler suggested removing some of the attributes as they weren't needed so I did.

I have been googling and cracking my head on this for 2 days now, and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but this is how I'd first try to do this:

```
[DllImport("MeshPlugin")]
private static extern bool ImportMesh(ref MeshData meshData);
```

and if it still doesn't work, I'd try to change the struct declaration to:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
private struct MeshData
{
    public IntPtr vertices;
    public int verticeCount;
}
MeshData meshData = new MeshData();
meshData.vertices = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (...);
// copy vertex data to the unmanaged array
meshData.verticeCount = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Rolf. The funny thing is that the vertices array is already working, it's the ints in the struct that aren't. In your suggested change I don't see any change in how the verticeCount is marshaled? Cheers!

Comment: A ref parameter isn't necessarily marshalled the same way as a [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] parameter :)

Comment: But are you saying then I need to do the Marshal.AllocHGlobal on everything? E.g. the MeshData gets a Marshal.AllocHGlobal and also the vertices array gets a separate one?

Comment: No, I have two suggestions, first **just** change the DllImport. Then if that doesn't work, use Marshal.AllocHGlobal to do manual marshalling of the vertex array.

Comment: I made the base struct ref and allocated the memory for the sub-arrays as suggested and it does work. Thanks. The problem is then I need to manually copy/marshal the sub-array data back and forth and it's real messy because the Marshal.Copy doesn't support structures, and the PtrToStructure can't work either in this config. It ended up being a whole lot of code. So for now, my solution was to use my original code, but stuff the verticeCount into an int array too. Thanks again for taking time to help!